# Preposition phrase-of college

Tags: grammar

> While I was home for the summer after my first semester **of college**, I decided to work in a store to earn some extra cash.

Is the preposition phrase "Of college" a noun complement of semester?

Comment: You ask as if there were a universal definition of "noun complement" in English. Do you have access to one?

Comment: @ John Lawler. I am sorry. To be honest, I am not understanding the concept of the noun complement. Sometime, I think it as adjective phrase describing the noun. I started reading the grammar book especifically  modern books, but I am not getting proper definition and their role in noun phrases.

Comment: *Of college* works like *college* semester, as a modifier: noun working as adjective.

Comment: I don't understand many people's uses of it. I have my own usages, but I've been a professional linguist for a long time and fads change. I think it's a question-begging term that does not have an agreed definition. I only use the word _complement_ to denote a dependent clause that's an argument (subject, object) of a higher clause. And this is definitely not one of those. So where did the question come from? If you're taking a class, ask your teacher to give a definition and syntactic tests.

Comment: @ John lawler. "So where did the question come from? If you're taking a class, ask your teacher to give a definition and syntactic tests". No, I am not taking. From India, I am not familiar with it; I learned noun phrase and 4 complements(object, subject, Adjective, and Adverb) but not noun complement as such. That is why I asked it. I read farlex and other books yet I didn't see it properly.

Comment: @ John lawler. As you mentioned you have been a professional linguist. It is my privilege to interact with English linguist through this forum. Thank to this forum. Would  you care to give some books or anything in order to strong my foundation . Thank you.

Comment: If your definition of complement is something that is necessary to complete a grammatical structure, then "of college" obviously isn't a complement because "While I was home for the summer after my first semester, I decided to work in a store to earn some extra cash." is fine. There are that many different ways of naming grammatical structures, I'm wary of answering any question like this.

Comment: Defining _complement_ as "something necessary to complete a grammatical sentence" is hopeless. Who gets to decide what's "necessary"? How does one decide when something is "completed"? One needs clear yes/no tests for syntactic phenomena. Also, it sounds like you're mixing up terms from different theories. Some people call predicate nouns "noun complements", I've found; I don't, since they're not clauses and they already have a name. No doubt predicate adjectives are called "adjective complements" by some, but I don't try to keep up.

Comment: @user465781 If you leave a gap between the @ sign and the name of the user you're trying to contact they may not get pinged, and thus might not read your comment!